# C# issues ComboBox and Suggestions from Database

Tags: c#, visual-studio, combobox, autocomplete, autosuggest

I am using a Winform with a comboBox, which is set to AutoCompleteMode = suggest
and AutoCompleteSource = List.

The values for the AutoCompletion are stored within a SQLite Database.
Due to the huge amount of data in that table, it doesn't make sense to load all values when the form will be created.

Insted, I wanted to run the Query against the user Input.
f.E. the User types "S" -> then the Query should return only the Values "... WHERE x LIKE `S%`;

This is working fine - with one strange behave, which I haven't figured out yet.

To prevent, that the SQL query will be fired without an empty string, I am using the following code:

```
    private void cb_City_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Globals.UseAutoFillOnCities == true)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cb_city.Text))
            {
                foreach (DataRow AutoFillItems in dbAction.GetAutoComplete("CITIES", cb_city.Text).Rows)
                {
                    AutoFillCities.Add(AutoFillItems[0].ToString());

                }
                cb_city.DataSource = AutoFillCities;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, to the strange behave of my Form:
When I run the Application, and go to my comboBox,
I am starting with Typing "S" into it.

But then, the comboBox.Text will be appended by the first match in my Database which is NOT starting with "S" instead, with "A" (like I have done the Query without any string for the LIKE statement.

But also, why does the comboBox is showing this value, instead of just showing the dropdown?

If I delete each Character in the ComboBox and try it again everything is working as expected.
It is only the first behave after the form was created.

[EDIT]
Thanks @dafie:

Thanks, I have changed this (also this was one of my tries earlier) - but then, the Control also behaves in a strange way.

When I am typing the first letter, nothing happens (it will not show the list with the suggestions).
When I then type the second Letter, it will remove the first character I have typed, only the second one is visible, and the comboBox will append with the first suggestion of the Search with "S".

for example, I wanted to Type "St", then I will have t"Saal" in my combobox.
(Saal is the first result for the search with "S")

The question is: Why does the ComboBox append the Text, if I only set the AutoComplete Method to "suggest"?
And why will my first input be removed?

Comment: by the way:
I have tried keyDown and keyPress event for the code above.

Comment: What event are you using to fire your code?

Comment: I've tried the KeyDown and KeyPress Event for cb_city:

private void cb_City_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        { }

Answer (score 1):

I think, I have found a solution which seems to work as I expected :)

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataRow AutoFillItems in GetAutoComplete("CITIES", comboBox1.Text).Rows)
        {
            AutoFillCities.Add(AutoFillItems[0].ToString());
        }

        foreach (string item in AutoFillCities)
        {
            comboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(item);
        }

        comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
```

Unfortunately, it is a bit ugly, using two foreach loops directly behind, but in my latest tests this has worked well.

I will now try it within my other project and if it will have the expected results, I will mark the question as solved.

Thanks for all your help :)

Comment: after implementing this into my origin project, everything is working as expected.
This seems to be the solution for my opening issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you fire this method before `cb_city.Text` is filled with text. You should change `cb_city.Text != null` to `!String.IsNullOrEmpty(cb_city.Text)`, because your code can check condition when `cb_city.Text` is set to `""`.

Comment: Hi Dafi, thanks.
But this didn't work as expected.

I have eddited my question below with the results from your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It's changing your combobox item because you are setting the datasource.

The data source is not what's used for the AutoComplete.

Instead you should be using the AutoCompleteCustomSource.

EX:

```
List<string> AutoData = new List<string>{ "Anthony", "Aaron", "Adam", "Ben", "Brian", "Charles", "Chuck", "Dan"};

private void comboBox1_TextUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                var items = AutoData.Where(a => a.StartsWith(comboBox1.Text));
                comboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Clear();
                comboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(items.ToArray());
                comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
            }
```

Comment: Additionally you will need to handle issues with the cases being different.  EX: 'A' vs 'a'

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion.
As far as I can see, you are searching each items with 'a' in your List AutoData.
Right?

But to be honest, I don't knwo, which data I need to search for, until the user has typed his first character.
I have also used the TextUpdate event now, but then, each string will override the previous string - and I don't see any suggestion from the Form for my input :-(

The DataSource is working perfectly, if I use it without trying to reduce the data with the user-intput.

Comment: If I fill the DataSource before the form will be shown, everything is working smoothly.
Only the time, the form needs to load all the data is too long, because the Database contains nearly 20,000 City names... :-(

Comment: This is looking for items from the list (a) that starts with whatever is typed in the combobox (combobox1.Text).

Comment: ok, I will try it again within another project (without any other code) later today.
Right now, it seemed not to work as I expected...

Comment: Hi, I've now tested your suggestion, but now, the ComboBox will always show only the typed character.

No suggestion and nothing else.
if I type S and then t the t will replace the S

Comment: I think, I have found a solution by changing your code a bit :)
I will update my post above with it